# What does !< means?

Tags: bash

What does `!<` means in this bash script, and why it points to file that does not exist?

```
bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; npm start'
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL comes with a `pg_isready` command that should be used instead of this kind of hack (checks not just that the socket is available, but also that the database is actually usable)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is a negation operator.
Example:

```
while ! false; do
    echo "inside while loop"
    sleep 1
done
```

will be inside the loop forever since `! false` is always true.

`<` is another operator. It tells bash to read the specified file. It will succeed (return zero exit code) if file exists and is readable. Without left operand, the read results will be discarded.
Example: check for `/tmp/sample_file` existence:

```
if < /tmp/sample_file; then echo 'file exists'; fi
```

Thus, your code will run `sleep 1` in a loop while `/dev/tcp/db/5432` cannot be read.

Now take into account that `/dev/tcp/` is a special path and accessing `/dev/tcp/db/5432` means trying to connect to host `db` via TCP port 5432.

So the logic behind your while loop is 'sleep until postgresql on host db is ready' (5432 is the default port for PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 5):

You should read that together with the file thats after `<`. The syntax `< file` opens the contents of the file for input redirection for any application to read over standard input.

In your specific syntax `</dev/tcp/db/5432` (tcp port on a remote host), the construct is defined just to verify is file is accessible for open for reading. The command will return successful exit code `0`, if file is accessible and `!` negates the exit code returned.

So basically the while loop in your example, sees `while 1`, if the file is accessible, which in the shell context means a non-zero exit code return, which doesn't let the sleep to happen at all. It is not entirely clear if your intention was to sleep until the file is available to open or the other way.

Comment: I would also mention that `/dev/tcp/db/5432` is not an ordinary file but a tcp port on a remote host called `db`.

Comment: I think a space would be required between ! and < as well?